# Infinispan Server : How to enable JMX monitoring?

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, infinispan

I have an **Infinispan Server**, version 6.0.x, the one derived from JBoss 7.2, and it is working fine for caching.

However, when I try to monitor it by JMX I can't. This is **URL** I type in `jconsole.bat` :

```
service:jmx:remoting-jmx://MY.IP.ADDRESS.HERE:9999
```

But I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "VMPanel.connect" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorProvider: Provider org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnectorProvider could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/Logger
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:377)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.getConnectorAsService(JMXConnectorFactory.java:472)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(JMXConnectorFactory.java:341)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:267)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:370)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:313)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:292)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/Logger
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnectorProvider.<clinit>(RemotingConnectorProvider.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 14 more
Exception in thread "VMPanel.connect" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorProvider: Provider org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnectorProvider could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnectorProvider
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:377)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.getConnectorAsService(JMXConnectorFactory.java:472)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(JMXConnectorFactory.java:341)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:267)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:357)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:313)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:292)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnectorProvider
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
    ... 7 more
```

Maybe I should create some managed beans somewhere? How can I fix this?

**Remark 1** : In the documentation they include the necearry configuration between `<global></global>`, but in my case the settings should respect JBoss Schema...

**Remark 2** : I tried with JBoss 7.2, and it could show me graphs and so on, and by the way I used the same URL. The difference is that I used `jconsole.bat` of JBoss instead of Infinispan.

Please, any idea about the necessary configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it work if you use the `jconsole.bat` from JBoss to monitor Infinispan Server?

Comment: I have downloaded JDG 6.3.2 and I am facing the same issue . Added all the missing jars to class ( jboss-logging , jboss-remote , xnio etc ) and still it fails to connect

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Windows 7 user, and this is the fix that worked for me.
Open **jconsole.bat** for editting.
At the top, turn on the echoing.

```
@echo on
```

Then go down and find this line

```
call :SearchForJars "%JBOSS_MODULEPATH%\system\layers\base\org\jboss\logging\main"
```

Insert the following line before it:

```
echo "%JBOSS_MODULEPATH%\system\layers\base\org\jboss\logging\main"
```

I'm not sure why that worked, but it did. If you get different ClassNotFound exceptions, try echo statements above the other jar searches.