# jmx monitoring for JDG 6.3.2

Tags: datagrid, jboss, infinispan, jboss-cache

We have been using Infinispan 5.2 and it has been working fine close to one year now.
We use the below URL to monitor infinispan and the cache statistics is displayed in our application for easy monitoring

service:jmx:rmi://IP_ADDRESS/jndi/rmi://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/jmxrmi

We are now migrating to JDG 6.3.2 so the JBOSS support can be purchased.
After moving to JDG 6.3.2 . The jmx url used for infinispan no longer works.

As per the below link - there is a jconsole within JDG which is supposed to be used but that is also not working

[Infinispan Server : How to enable JMX monitoring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901772/infinispan-server-how-to-enable-jmx-monitoring)

Has  anybody faced this issue ?

Thanks

Lives

Comment: Hello, can you please try out these 2 addresses and let me know? service:jmx:remoting-jmx://{YOUR.IP.ADDRESS}:9999 or service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://{YOUR.IP.ADDRESS}:9990 and you can also try to switch 9990 and 9999 in case I messed that up.

Comment: Also, while it seems you are in a product evaluation phase, you can also contact company support and subject matter experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options here...

1. Use JBoss On or RHQ (recommended)
2. Use Hawt.io
3. Use attached jconsole ($JDG_HOME/bin/jconsole.sh)
4. Use JVisual VM, but please remember to add JBoss client to the classpath (`jvisualvm -cp:a $JDG_HOME/bin/client/jboss-client.jar`). After that, please use `service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://$JDG_IP:9990` (assuming default configuration).

Please remember that for JMX connection you will also need to create a user attached to Management Realm (`$JDG_HOME/bin/add-user.sh -u <username> -p <password> -r ManagementRealm -e -s`)

Comment: Thanks - That was useful information which I could not find. Will try the fourth option since I am trying to connect  remotely from windows machine to the JDG installed in linux